# Planning, Scaling and Optimizing Large Web Application

Tags: php, mysql, soap, web

I'm currently designing and developing a web application that has the potential to grow very large at a fast rate. I will give some general information and move on to my question(s). I would say I am a mid-level web programmer.

Here are some specifications:
MySQL - Database Backend
PHP - Used in front/backend. Also used for SOAP Client
HTML, CSS, JS, jQuery - Front end widgets (highcharts, datatables, jquery-ui, etc.)

I can't get into too many fine details as it is a company project, but the main objective is to construct a dashboard that thousands of users will be accessing from various devices.

The data for this project is projected to grow by 50,000 items per year ( ~1000 items per week ).

1 item = 1 row in database

An item will also record a daily history starting at the day it was inserting.

1 day of history per item = 1 record

365 records per 1 year per device

365 * 50,000 = ~18,500,000 [first year]

multiply ~18,500,000 records by x for each year after.

(My forumla is a bit off since items will be added periodically throughout that year)

All items and history are accessed through a SOAP Client that connects to an API service, then writes the record to the database.

Majority of this data will be read and remain static (read only). But some item data may be updated or changed. The data will also be updated each day and need to write another x amount of history.

Questions:

1) Is MySQL a good solution to handle these data requirements? ~100 million records at some point.

2) I am limited to synchronous calls with my PHP Soap Client (as far as I know). This is becoming time consuming as more items are being extracted. Is there a better option for writing a SOAP Client so that I can send asynchronous requests without waiting for a response?

3) Are there any other requirements I should be thinking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Is MySQL a good solution to handle these data requirements? ~100 million records at some point.**

Absolutely. Make sure you've got everything indexed properly, and if you hit a storage or query-per-second limit, you've got plenty of options that apply to most/all DBMS's. You can get beefier hardware, start sharding data across servers, clustering, etc..

**2) I am limited to synchronous calls with my PHP Soap Client (as far as I know). This is becoming time consuming as more items are being extracted. Is there a better option for writing a SOAP Client so that I can send asynchronous requests without waiting for a response?**

PHP 5+ allows you to execute multiple requests in parallel with CURL. Refer to the curl_muli* function for this, such as [curl_multi_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php). As far as I know, this requires you to handle SOAP/XML processing disjointly from the requests.

**3) Are there any other requirements I should be thinking about?**

Probably. But, you're usually on the right track if you start with a properly indexed, normalized database, for which you've thought about your objects at least *mostly* correctly. Start denormalizing if/when you find instances wherein denormalization solves an existing or *obvious* near-future efficiency problem. But, don't optimize for things that could become problems if the moons of Saturn align. Only optimize for problems that users will notice somewhat regularly.

Comment: svidgen, thanks for the feedback. In terms of SOAP, I need to have a way to send out multiple requests and set up call backs to push the response to MySQL. With PHP, I send a request and wait until I get a response. I wish to send out 10-20 requests at once, and handle responses accordingly. The soap client would be a script set up in cron (unless there is a better way ;))

Comment: Thank you, I found a class that extends the soapclient and uses curl!

Comment: i would recommend the node js for the SOAP Client for asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty involved in scaling is almost always a function of *users* times *data*. If you have a lot of users, but not much data, it's not hard to scale. A typical example is a popular blog. Likewise, if you have a lot of data but not very many users, you're also going to be fine. This represents things like accounting systems or data-warehouse situations.

The first step towards any solution is to rough in a schema and test it **at scale**. You will have no idea how your application is going to perform until you run it through the paces. No two applications ever have exactly the same problems. Most of the time you'll need to adjust your schema, de-normalize some data, or cache things more aggressively, but these are just techniques and there's no standard cookbook for scaling.

In your specific case you won't have many problems if the rate of `INSERT` activity is low and your indexes aren't too complicated. What you'll probably end up doing is splitting out those hundreds of millions of rows into several identical tables each with a much smaller set of records in them.

If you're having trouble getting your queries to execute, consider the standard approach: index, optimize, then denormalize, then cache.

Where PHP can't cut it, consider using something like Python, Ruby, Java/Scala or even NodeJS to help facilitate your database calls. If you're writing a SOAP interface, you have many options.

Answer (score 0):

While talking about large scale app the all the efforts and credits should not be given to the database alone. However it is the core part as our data in the main thing in any web aplication and side my side the your application depends upon the code optimization too that includes your backend and frontend script. Images and mainly server. Oh god many factors affecting the application.